# Using DataTable as a Table Valued Parameter in EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, table-valued-parameters

[Updated problem description]
We have a bulk import process for which we were passing `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` as a Table Valued Parameter (TVP) to a Stored Proc, as `DataTable` Type was not available until EF Core 1.1. We just upgraded our project to use .Net Core 2.0 and started updating the code to use DataTable. The **ExecuteSqlCommandAsync** command started throwing an `InvalidCastException`. 
Here are the exception details:

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Failed to convert parameter value from a DataTable to a IEnumerable`1.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildParamList(TdsParser parser, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildExecuteSql(CommandBehavior behavior, String commandText, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback callback, Object stateObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsync(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endMethod, Object state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.<ExecuteSqlCommandAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at X.Y.Repositories.Repository.<Import>d__4.MoveNext() in Repository.cs:line 95
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at X.Y.Services.ImportService`2.<BulkImportAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in ImportService.cs:line 70

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
```

This is how I am calling the stored proc:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(String));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(String)); //and so on

foreach (var record in records)
{
    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
    SetStringValue(row, "Col1", record.Field1); //SetStringValue is just a helper method that assigns DBNull.Value if the field value is null. 
    SetStringValue(row, "Col2", record.Field2); //and so on

    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}

var param = new SqlParameter("@Records", dataTable)
{
    TypeName = "TVPRecords",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
};

await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC dbo.ImportData @Records", param);
```

With `DataTable` now available in EF Core 2.0, I still can't use it to pass as a TVP to a Stored Proc. Is it because its not supported yet or may be a bug?

Comment: Are you saying this did work with EF Core 1.1 ? Better be clear about the parts of the problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've updated the problem description.

Comment: The exception suggests it expects a `IEnumerable<>`, so what if you replace the DataTable with a `List<ClassWithCol1Col2>`

Comment: I doubt it was ever supported. Check out this answer in MSDN [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31fcfae8-64d5-4a28-9515-b35af0b21522/list-collection-is-passe-as-table-values-parameters-error-failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a?forum=adodotnetdataproviders). I guess the only working option available now is to use IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.

Comment: Yes, DataTable with Core 2  surprised me. That's very old tech.

Answer (score 9):

The only possible error I could find in your code is the `SqlParameter`'s `TypeName`. Yours is not fully qualified, I needed to include the schema, i.e. "dbo.".

I'm using EFCore 2.0.2 and EFCore.SqlServer 2.0.2

This is my code:

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FieldId", typeof(int)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(double)));
foreach (Value v in NewRows)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["FieldId"] = v.FieldId;
    row["Value"] = v.Value;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

var param = new SqlParameter("@replacementValues", table) { TypeName = "dbo.CustomSqlType", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured };
await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC dbo.UpdateValues @replacementValues", param);
```