# Query many objects by list of ids with ef core and no User-Defined Table Types

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a list of ids of objects i want to get. The list can be to big to use
`context.MyObject.Where(obj=> myIdList.Contains(obj.Id))`. It's possible to have over 10000 entries.

The solution should be to create a temporary table like here: [Create temporary list/table in SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21160840/9764940). I can do that in SQL with the values and select the rows i need with a join. It would look like this:

```
declare @idTable table (Id int)
insert into @idTable values (1), (2), (5), (7), (10)....

select MyTable.* from MyTable
inner join @idTable as ids on ids.Id= MyTable.Id
```

And something similar is possible with ef core as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866232/9764940):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
        
foreach (int id in myIdList)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = v.FieldId;
   
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

var param = new SqlParameter("@idTable", table) { TypeName = "dbo.CustomSqlType", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured };
var myObjects = context.MyObject.FromRawSql("select MyTable.* from MyTable
inner join @idTable as ids on ids.Id= MyTable.Id", param);
```

But for this to work in ef-core i need User-Defined Table Types. Because of the nature of the database i would prefer not to do that. This -> `TypeName = "dbo.CustomSqlType"` is missing and i cant create it on the server. And the sql above shows it is possible without.
The other alternative to creating a User-Defined Table Types is to create a big sql-string every time to execute. I would not like to to that for security reasons (i dont trust myself escaping that and i should not) and i want to be able to reuse the code so i can retrieve objects by idLists from other tables.
Is it possible to do what i want without User-Defined Table Types in a reusable way in ef-core?

---

If this is not possible in ef-core i would be happy about an alternative with another framework or tool for .netcore too.

Comment: Have you tried the basic version? `var ids = new [] { 1, 2, 5, 7, 10 }; context.MyObject.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.id))`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes. As i said the List is to big for that. The server times out and i think in general a contain with over ~1000 List entries should be avoided as it is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping everything in `FromSql`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad No but i would prefer a solution where i am able to escape the sql params in a normal way but if nothing else is possible i will try that.

Comment: I see what you are saying, how about a UDF?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad  I wish. The database has a lot of legacy stuff and i would realy prefer a query that only uses temporary variables and doesnt need more than read permission. No lasting changes on the database are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Create a model(table) in the database with two fields

```
public class SelectedRecord
{
     public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
     public Guid RecordId { get; set; }
}
```

Then before querying thousands of records, insert records you want to select

```
var groupId = Guid.NewGuid();
var selectedRecords = 
    ids.Select(id => new SelectedRecord { GroupId = groupId, RecordId = id })
       .ToArray();
context.SelectedRecords.AddRange(selectedRecords);

var objects = context.SelectedRecords
    .Where(selected => selected.GroupId == groupId)
    .Join(context.MyObjects,
        selected => selected.RecordId,
        object => object.Id,
        (_, object) => object
     )
     .ToArray();
```

Of course this will require inserting thousands of the records, but inserting to the table with only two columns can be quicker than running `IN (id1, id2, ..., id99999)`

Comment: its not the perfect solution but i think it is the cleanest without being afraid of touching existing stuff