# Is there a way to make foreach loop faster while inserting data into database inside a loop?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm inserting message into database for each member inside a `foreach` loop which makes the application slow as it is going to run 200+ times to add message for each member. I tried to make it parallel `foreach` loop but that would throw error of connection was open while saving data and I have multiple `foreach` loop.

Anybody to help out here?

```
foreach (var item in coachee)
    {
        MessageRecord MsgRecord = new MessageRecord();
        MsgRecord.MessageID = msgID;
        MsgRecord.CoachID = coachID;
        MsgRecord.CoacheeID = item.CoacheeIdentityID;
        MsgRecord.CreatedBy = Session["user"].ToString();
        MsgRecord.IsActive = 1;
        MsgRecord.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        message.DocumentPath = DocumentPath;

        bool val = await _repoObjCoach.AddMessageRecordForCoacheeasync(MsgRecord);
        if (val)
        {

            coacheeMails.Add(item.EmailID);
            if (item.Parent_Email != null)
            {
                ParentMails.Add(item.Parent_Email);
            }
            if (item.PhoneMail != null)
            {
                PhoneMails.Add(item.PhoneMail);
            }
           
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Role"]) == ConstantData.Role.Coach)
        {
            _repoObjCoach.MessageCreatedNotification(MessageCreatedByCoach.Coachee + Session["user"].ToString(), string.Concat(LinkPageMessageCreated.coachee, item.UserID.ToString()), "", item.CoacheeIdentityID);
        }
        else
        {
            _repoObjCoach.MessageCreatedNotification(MessageCreatedByCoach.alternateCoachee + Session["user"].ToString(), string.Concat(LinkPageMessageCreated.coachee, item.UserID.ToString()), "", item.CoacheeIdentityID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered batching?

Comment: please suggest how to implement that in current scenario

Comment: try bulk insert, create a `DataTable` in the `foreach` loop and then insert it to the DB, please see here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-in-sql-server-from-c-sharp

Comment: @kshkarin- thanx will try that, but will that be  efficient if sometimes I only have 20 records to insert ?

Comment: @AnkitBist Have you tried [SqlBulkCopy](https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-fast-inserts/)?

Comment: @PeterCsala - but thats not efficient if sometimes i need to insert less number of rows?

Comment: @AnkitBist You can't optimize a single solution for multiple different workloads. But you can branch based on some heuristic. For example under 20 items you can use multiple inserts or a stored procedure with TVP (table valued parameters) and above 20 you can utilize SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: @PeterCsala - thanx for the help will try that

Comment: @PeterCsala- but im using entity framework

Comment: @AnkitBist That's should not be a problem. EF does [support TVP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866232/13268855). There is a nuget package which wraps SqlBulkCopy functionality and expose it to EFCode. It is called [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions). Or if you prefer to use lower-level APIs then take a look at the [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader), which makes your SqlBulkCopy command super easy.

Comment: @PeterCsa;a - thanx my man i'll try that